# What are the requirements for the lifejacket badge?

Tags: discussion, badges

I have become a [proud holder](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8841/lifejacket?userid=3764965) of the 'Lifejacket' badge an hour ago. It seems it has been introduced recently. From its [description](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8841/lifejacket):

> Answer score of 5 or more to a question score of -2 or less that goes on to receive a score of 2 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

It means it is required that the question starts with **-2** total score (upvotes and downvotes difference) and raises up to at least a positive **2** score, I have to provide an answer with a score at least **5**. So far so good.

I am only confused about the following:

1. Do I have to answer the question ***at the moment*** the score is negative (for example **-2**) and its score gets improved over the time my answer has been posted?
2. Does this badge mean: *"Hey, you have rescued this question and helped to attach upvoters thanks to your fairly good answer and a probable edit! Thank you!"*?

Comment: It means -2 when the answer is posted. If it's at -1 with -3 +2 with your answer posted at +1, that doesn't qualify your answer to receive it.

Comment: @Zoe: You might want to post it as an answer or wait to "rescue" this one.

Comment: Minor concern, but since votes are meant to be private, if I get a badge and the question ends up with exactly +3 votes, it would be easy to work out that one of those votes was mine. Is this a problem or just a fringe event that might not happen or even have anyone care about?

Comment: @DavidG: Your vote doesn't count toward the badge, so there's nothing to work out.

Comment: @KenWhite It's because my vote doesn't count that makes it discoverable.  If the question ticks from +2 to +3, and triggers me getting the badges, then one of those previous upvotes must have been mine.

Comment: @DavidG: No, **your vote** does not count at all toward your earning the badge. Read the blog post related to the badge, or the answer below. Your own vote does not count.

Comment: @KenWhite Yes I know! But if the question is already at +2 and I don't have the badge, then one of those upvotes must be mine because it doesn't count towards the badge!

Comment: The good news is we can award it multiple times.

Comment: @DavidG I've just asked the question here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329711/does-lifejacket-potentially-disclose-one-of-your-vote

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> 1. Do I have to answer the question ***at the moment*** the score is negative (for example **-2**) and its score gets improved over the time my answer has been posted?

Yes. Do note that your own downvote on the question doesn't count for the -2 check.

> 2. Does this badge mean: *"Hey, you have rescued this question and helped to attach upvoters thanks to your fairly good answer and a probable edit! Thank you!"*?

Yes, that's more or less the intention. From the [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/):

> **These badges reward reversing the score of a negative question by answering it** in a way that sheds new, positive light on the question, raising its score. It’s an answer so good it makes the question look good by association!

Comment: So you can't game the system and downvote -1 question to make it eligible, good.

Comment: @Nikolas: the system awards them retroactively.  e.g. I got [7 of them all at once](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8841/lifejacket?userid=224132).  :P  I probably would have had fewer if my votes counted, because I upvoted most of those questions before answering, and many of them only had a couple downvotes.  (Although some of them must have had downvotes removed, because one is only at `-1`)

Comment: Note that this answer is slightly incorrect, as [clarified by Animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329712/261748). Votes do count, but only to get the question to -2 score.

Comment: Thanks - with such complicated qualification requirements I was bound to make a mistake somewhere.

Comment: @DavidG You mean "but only to get the question to +2 score", right?

Comment: I upvoted this answer due to the writer's handle.  That's one of my favorite characters.  Oh and the content is ok too. Feel free to drop some more gems to signify safe passage.